# Transformation of an epoxido-carboxylic acid to an aldehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

> [image]

So I am battling with the last part of this transformation and was hoping someone could explain this mechanism to me so that I can confirm my answer.

Treating an alcohol with a strong hydrohalic acid results in the formation of alkyl halide and proceeds through an S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanism. (Protonation of alcohol on the carboxylic acid, then loss of $\ce{H2O}$ to form a carbocation) But $\ce{HCl}$ is supposed to give a substitution reaction and not an elimination reaction. So I am unsure how the final product is formed.

Comment: Looking at the product, we can see there's a decarboxylation here due to the "heat". I bet the $\ce{HCl}$ is only to perform acidic cleavage of the epoxide. Though I am unsure how to knit both of them together.

Comment: Previously addressed. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86726/epoxide-ring-opening-via-decarboxylation/86729#86729